# Racket Iterate over list and get Index

Tags: functional-programming, racket

Im learning Racket and have some troubles.

I want to iterate over a list and find the index of some value. I have the following code:

```lisp
(define (index list entry)
  (define index 0)
  (for ([i list])
    #:break (equal? i entry)
    (+ index 1))
    index)
```

But the function always returns 0. Can anyone point out my mistake?

I know that there are functions for that, but I want to learn the syntax.

Comment: If you do `$test + 1` in PHP does `$test` get incremented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of, the easiest way to get the index of an element in a list is `index-of`:

```
> (index-of '(1 3 5 2 4) 5)
2
```

Another way I will sometimes do it is using the `in-naturals` sequence. So taking your code:

```
(define (index list entry)
  (for/last ([i list]
             [index (in-naturals)])
    #:break (equal? i entry)
    index))
```

This works because `for` loop constructs iterates as many times as the shortest sequence. `in-naturals` will go on forever, so it will count only as many elements are in `list`, and still break when your `#:break` clause is met.

A third option is to use `for/fold`, again based on your code:

```
(define (index list entry)
  (for/fold ([acc 0])
            ([i list])
    #:break (equal? i entry)
    (add1 acc)))
```

This works because `acc` acts as an accumulator, and gets incremented every iteration until your `#:break` clause is met.

Finally, your original code has two primary problems.

First, the `for` form always returns `(void)`. You need to use `for/last` if you want it to return the last element.

Second, the `+` function only adds two numbers. It does not store the result back into the variable. So if you really want to use mutation here, you would need to do:

```
(define (index list entry)
  (define index 0)
  (for ([i list])
    #:break (equal? i entry)
    (set! index (+ index 1)))
  index)
```

But again, I highly recommend just using `index-of`, since its already in the standard library.

Comment: Thank you! I stumpled on the problem, because my school only has V6.1 (or so) and it wasn´t added in this version.

Comment: Ya, `index-of` was added in either 6.7 or 6.8.